# How to measure when error stabilizes (convergence) on Random Forests (or, when do I stop training)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, error

I'm doing an implementation of Random Forests. As I was [the original paper](http://www.vision.rwth-aachen.de/teaching/ml/lecture/fulltext.pdf) (page 11) and [this nice book on the subject](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf) (15.3.1, page 592), they mention that when the out-of-bags error stabilizes (when our solution converges) as more trees are being trained, the training can be stopped *before* actually getting to train all the trees.

That's very nice, but I haven't found a way to do it. I was thinking of a naive approach, having a window of the last trees trained and calculating the variance or the stddev of the error. After one of these values goes below a threshold (also naively defined by... me) then training can stop.

Is there a well-known approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably just a start, but have you tried tuneRF() in randomForest in R?
The *improve* argument lets you specify the relative improvement in OOB error for the search to continue. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf

Comment: This does help a lot, I hadn't thought of looking for R's reference implementation. Thanks!